# Count lines between two date and timestamp

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Create new log file when process goes to next day for a nohup script. For now getting the count when it switches to next date will suffice

Below is the sample data

```
script.ksh 2024/02/19 23:59:59
script.ksh 2024/02/20 00:00:00
script.ksh 2024/02/20 00:00:01
```

I am looking to grep script when it reaches next day, but its not able to grep and genete count of matching data when running in background.

While same fetches data when executed through command line.

```
grep -E '2024/02/20' | wc -l

sed -n '\#2024/02/20 00:00:0#, \2024/02/20 00:00:0#p'| wc -l
```

Tried with grep -E and SED. Grep -E and sed are not able to return desired output within script but works in command line and not in nohup

Comment: "I am looking to grep script when it reaches next day, but its not working." doesn't tell us [what you're really trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78018365/linux-grep-lines-between-two-date-and-timestamp#comment137543875_78019109), nor does it show us your attempt to solve the problem yourself, nor does it tell us in what way it's not working ("it's not working" is famously the most inadequate problem statement).

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
script.ksh 2024/02/19 23:59:59
script.ksh 2024/02/20 00:00:00
script.ksh 2024/02/20 00:00:01
```

then

```
awk '{d=$2;gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"",d);print $0 > ("file" d ".txt")}' file.txt
```

creates `file20240219.txt` holding

```
script.ksh 2024/02/19 23:59:59
```

and `file20240220.txt` holding

```
script.ksh 2024/02/20 00:00:00
script.ksh 2024/02/20 00:00:01
```

Explanation: I store 2nd field value in variable `d`, then remove all non-digits in `d` (observe that using `/` in filename is bad idea, as it looks like path, if you find 8 digits unreadable you might elect to replace with `_` rather than empty string, which will result in `2024_02_19` and `2024_02_20`). Then I `print` current line (`$0`) to file named `file` followed by what is stored in variable d followed by `.txt`. **Disclaimer** this solution assumes that number of distinct days in your file is lesser than number of files GNU `AWK` is able to open at once.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Thanks, this would not be ideal because the script will continue to write in actual log file which was created days ago. Idea is to create separate log files daily while process continues to run in background

Comment: @Emma that is not stated in your question and is by far the most important requirement so please edit your question to state what it is you';re trying to do and show your attempt to solve the problem yourself.